# How to insert DateTime in database, by default saving as 0000-00-00 00:00:00?

Tags: php

I'm coding CMS (website backed) I want to insert current datetime as publish date, but when ever I clicked on submit button it store every field correctly but datetime field showing 0000 00 000 00000 problem.

```
<p>Published DateTime : </p>

<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');  
  $datetime = new DateTime();
  $dt = $datetime->format('d-m-Y @ h:i A');
?>

<input type="text" name="dt" value="<?php echo $dt; ?>" readonly />

<?php
   if($_POST['submit'])
   {
     $dt = $_POST['dt'];
   }

INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('$dt');
```

Every time when I click on submit button every field is inserted except datetime, the error result is showing in database is  0000 00 00 000000. I want to store current datetime into database.

Comment: did you check $dt value? Let post your code insert database.

Comment: double check `$dt` variable value before inserting into database

Comment: Yes i checked $dt value my problem is 0000 00 00 00000 formate saving in database... i want current date formate

Comment: datetime format in database should be `$datetime->format('Y-m-d h:i:s)`. make sure you are inserting in that format.

Comment: **yasaryousuf** Thanks dude, it's worked know i have been try my code i.e. format('d-m-Y @ h:i A'), and i was thinking where i'm lacking but you detect my error..  A Simple miskate ('Y-m-d h:i:s') makes my whole code crap... thanks once again..